# Classify images with different number of data for each class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have 7 class of images which I need to classify. Each class has a different number of sample.

1. 75 Images
2. 70 Images
3. 98 Images
4. 182 Images
5. 146 Images
6. 197 Images
7. 150 Images

I ended up removing all images in all class down to 70 images (50 Training and 20 Validation). Using Keras and the generator and flow_from_directory method, I able to classify all of them, but it's obvious that I won't get a good accuracy. I have a plan to augment the data too later.

My Question is, can I use different number of training data for each class using flow_from_directory method? And is there any potential drawback with this method?

For example :

1. 55 Training - 20 Validation
2. 50 Training - 20 Validation
3. 78 Training - 20 Validation
4. ......

Thanks

Comment: I believe different number of samples will work, but your model will be biased towards more frequent classes. At the ratios you have this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I have heard that the biased classification appears, when your batch size becomes small compared to the number of classes and the probability of their occurence in the batch. E.g. if you have like in the example 7 classes, but only 10 images in a batch, than you have high probability of some class not being represented in a batch. I heard you can avoid the problem by just making your batch large enough to accommodate images from all classes, e.g. in the example above batch_size=150 images. Would you say the claims I report are valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's better to equalize the number of training samples in each class, or the classifier may tend to classify an image to the class in which there are most training samples.

Say, maybe you can double the training samples in class 2 (by copying and pasting)?

And for data augmentation, you can add noises to you training sample, say add Gaussian noises, crop and resize the images, and so on. By doing this, the model will be more robust.